# 404 error page redirect to home page using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to redirect 404 error page to home page.

I used below code to redirect 404 page to home page but this code working in one scenrio.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

It's working for **www.domain.com/slug1** this type of URL

But it's not working for **www.domain.com/slug1/slug2/slug3....** this type of urls.

Please suggest any solution for this issue.

Comment: @S.I. I didn't get solution

Comment: removed my flag then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Look [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130310123646/http://onlinemarketingexperts.com.au/2013/01/how-to-permanently-redirect-301-all-404-missing-pages-in-htaccess/) For More Help